# Как сделать так что-бы несколько потоков выполняли одну функцию? C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

void foo() {
 int i = 0;
    while (i != 100000) {
        cout << i << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
int main()
{ 
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    //*волшебная функция*(foo);
    system("pause>nul"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Если запустить этот код то выполняться он будет довольно долго, так-как надо вывести 100 тысяч элементов и всем этим занимается лишь 1 поток. Вопрос в том, как же мне сделать так что-бы этим занимался не 1 поток, а скажем 2? Или 4? Или сразу все 8? Может есть какая-нибудь волшебная функция?

Comment: Какая разница, сколько потоков пишут в `cout`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто добавьте перед выводом такое

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

в некоторых случаях это в раз десять добавит к [скорости вывода](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524568/cout-speed-when-synchronization-is-off).

Но тут есть ещё одна штука. Если пользуетесь стандартным консольным виндовым окно (а судя по двум system - это так и есть), то не забывайте, что она также достаточно "подтормаживает. Попробуйте установить [windows terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) - даже просто замена консоли может сильно-сильно ускорить вывод.

С другой стороны, размер буфера консоли вывода ограничена. Так что можно вывести просто последние пару тысяч, все равно никто не поймет.

Comment: И еще убрать `endl`, чтобы не сбрасывать буфер после каждой записи.

Comment: это надо вторым этап делать. когда вау эффект прошел и захотелось ещё чуточку. А можно формировать кусок строки сразу в памяти, а потом выдавать, думаю, по 1000-2000 строк сразу

Answer (score 1):

консоль разделяемый ресурс, поэтому в одно время только один поток может писать в неё безопасно, чтобы несколько потоков выполняли одну функцию смотрите в сторону например реализации многопоточности в стандартной библиотеки `std::thread` или `OpenMP` технологии

Comment: Уточню: из этого не следует, что несколько потоков, пишущих в `cout`, приводят к рэйсу, хотя данные могут печататься в произвольном порядке